# How to serialize hash objects in Python

Tags: python, serialization, hash, shelve

How can I serialize hash objects?, I'm using *shelve* to store a lot of objects.

Hierarchy:

```
- user
    - client
    - friend
```

user.py:

```
import time
import hashlib
from localfile import localfile

class user(object):
    _id = 0
    _ip = "127.0.0.1"
    _nick = "Unnamed"
    _files = {}
    def __init__(self, ip="127.0.0.1", nick="Unnamed"):
        self._id = hashlib.sha1(str(time.time()))
        self._ip = ip
        self._nick = nick
    def add_file(self, localfile):
        self._files[localfile.hash] = localfile
    def delete_file(self, localfile):
        del self._files[localfile.hash]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

client.py:

```
from user import user
from friend import friend

class client(user):
    _friends = []
    def __init__(self, ip="127.0.0.1", nick="Unnamed"):
        user.__init__(self, ip, nick)
    @property
    def friends(self):
        return self._friends
    @friends.setter
    def friends(self, value):
        self._friends = value
    def add_friend(self, client):
        self._friends.append(client)
    def delete_friend(self, client):
        self._friends.remove(client)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import shelve

    x = shelve.open("localfile", 'c')

    cliente = client()
    cliente.add_friend(friend("127.0.0.1", "Amigo1"))
    cliente.add_friend(friend("127.0.0.1", "Amigo2"))

    x["client"] = cliente
    print x["client"].friends

    x.close()
```

Errors:

```
facon@facon-E1210:~/Documentos/workspace/test$ python client.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 28, in <module>
    x["client"] = cliente
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 132, in __setitem__
    p.dump(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle HASH objects
```

**EDITED**

Added user.py.

Comment: Not every module needs an `if __name__ == '__main__'` block, it’s useless in user.py

Comment: You're right, user is supposes to be an abstract class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can't serialize `HASH` objects with `shelve`, you would have to provide the same information in a different way.  For example, you could only save the digest of the hash.

Comment: I need both things, keys (strings) and elements (objects that can be pickled). I'm thinking in putting both elements in 2 lists, one for keys and the other one for elements. But I don't know if later I can join lists correctly.

Comment: Then use a dictionary or list of tuples with 2 elements.

Comment: Omg!, I'm a fool, I only need to change this like you said: self._id = hashlib.sha1(str(time.time())) to self._id = hashlib.sha1(str(time.time())).hexdigest() then the object can be pickled. I thought that the hash was already a string. Thanks!!!!

Comment: `:)` Typical.  You could also use the `digest()` method of `HASH` objects.  The result of `hexdigest()` requires twice as much bytes (40 instead of 20), but it contains the same information.  Unless you want to print out the hash, you probably could do this...  But it's totally your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Something in `cliente`, the instance of `client` class, is not picklable.
Here is a [list of those types which are picklable](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled).

The code you've posted does not show what `cliente` contains which is not picklable. But you can solve the problem by either removing the unpicklable attribute if it is not needed, or by defining `__getstate__` and `__setstate` to make `client` picklable.

Comment: I posted the class that inherits from client which likely contains that "hash element", user, check now please. I also accept any criticism to improve my code.